# EC2 - MS Server 2012 constantly resetting its own time

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, time, time-synchronization, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 box of instance type m2.4xlarge running Windows Server 2012 Standard in a VPC in US-West-2. The following ports are open inbound:

`TCP 1433 (MS SQL)
TCP 3389 (RDP)
UDP 123 (time synch)`

... and the following outbound:

`UDP 37
UDP 123
TCP 80
TCP 443
TCP 1433`

I'm having an issue where this server consistently is resetting its own time (in this case, to be 7 minutes fast - always 7 minutes). We've tried messing with port settings, Windows firewall settings, changing time servers, pretty much everything we can think of. None of the other servers (a mish mosh of Win2008 R2 and Win2012 standard) have this issue, in various security groups (including the one outlaid above). We're starting to go somewhat batty, as this is our main database and having a time discrepancy is resulting in some absolutely wonky code issues. Has anyone run into a similar issue and, if so, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the underlying hardware clock was in a bad state, and kept overriding the NTP time sync (was pointed in the right direction by https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=519638). If anyone else is having this issue on EC2, you can contact Amazon to fix the underlying hardware.